# The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am working on a laravel project in which I am trying to show image using `url` but getting `error`. I have tried a lot and search everything but I don't understand why I am getting this error. I am using the below **function**

```php
    public function displayImage($filename){

        $path = storage_path("app/taskImage/".$filename);

        if (!File::exists($path)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $file = File::get($path);

        $type = File::mimeType($path);

        $response = \Response::make($file, 200);

        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

        return $response;
    }
```

And the **route** is

```php
Route::get('taskImg/{filename?}', [
        'uses' => 'FormController@displayImage',
    ]);
```

And the **URL** which I am tring is like

`http://localhost/project_name/public/taskImg/test.jpg`

when I have print something I am getting the that but Not getting the Image. It is showing a blank screen with error message **`The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors`**

Comment: Download that file, and try to open/load in gfx app to see. Then peek file content in any **text** editor to see if it is not polluted by i. E. Notice

Comment: i have 2 question 1. are you getting error in a single file or in all files 2. what exact url you are getting

Comment: I have downloaded the file from google chrome and paste it in my directory so I don't think image is corrupt. I have do the same for screen shot, mobile image and uploaded file but getting same problem.

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta, I am getting the same for all Images such as screen shot, capture from camera, downloaded images. Getting same for all The image “http://localhost/project_name/public/taskImg/test.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: paste this url in your chrome and see the image get load or not and let me know the responce of this

Comment: Try it like this `return Image::make($path)->response();` and see what you get !

Comment: Image is displaying when I am trying this in browser http://localhost/project_name/storage/app/taskImage/test.jpg

Comment: @Maraboc, this is laso not working, return Image::make($path)->response();

Comment: And I have to send that url in api response to open image so I have to use only url option to show image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent a LOT of hours searching for a solution for this, I found it at last! just add `ob_end_clean` before returning the response, like the following:

```
ob_end_clean();
        return response()->file($path,['Content-type' => 'image/jpeg']);
```

I can't explain because I don't know what was going on, any one could explain this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this way

```
$storagePath = storage_path("app/taskImage/".$filename);

return Image::make($storagePath)->response();
```

Comment: Getting this  Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Image' not found

Comment: Before using this class you have to include it in use statements above the class declration

Comment: I know and I am using return \Image::make($storagePath)->response();

Comment: I have do the same with aws server for other project. But I don't understand the exact problem that why it is not working on localhost

Comment: I want to know that where is you image stored in the project iys in public diractory or in storage diractory?

Comment: in storage directory, storage/app/taskImage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203219/discussion-between-yogendra-and-shaielndra-gupta).